# Proving that the space of linear operators is linear

Tags: linear-algebra

I was reading a book on linear spaces and in the part of linear operators the author claims that it's trivial to show that the space of linear operators is actually a linear space. I am struggling with proving the null element condition of linear spaces. Let's assume we are dealing with a set of operators $A : X \to Y$, where $X$ and $Y$ are two linear spaces. Having an operator $A$ and a null operator $O$ and considering their sum $(A+O)(x) = A(x)+O(x) = A(x)$, which takes place for every $x \in X$, can i claim that $A+O = A$? I haven't met any definition of operators being equal, is $A(x) = B(x)$ for every $x \in X$ enough to say, that $A=B$?

Comment: Operators (or functions or maps) are said to be equal if their domain is the same and their "assigment rule" is the same.For instance $\sin\colon [0,2\pi]\to \mathbb R$ is different from $\sin\colon \mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ because the domains are different. So to answer your questions: yes and yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes indeed. If A(x)=B(x) for every x then by definition A=B

Comment: Thanx for the reply. Understood!